# Making Eclipse Plugins: How to open class declaration from String e.g. "java.is.Good"

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to make a tool like this:

"java.is.Good.toString()" I want to search this String and jump to the Good.toString() method body.

how to active this?
I can read sourcecode of eclipse, but know nothing about eclipse plugins development, so please give me some guide just like:

THE KEY METHOD
 org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.MethodDeclarationMatch
 [I can't find where to turn a String path to a JavaElement for search]

THE KEY SAMPLE
 [I can't find the eclipse "navigate->open declaration" sourcecode]

Comment: This is totally for Making a read helper to easily navigate to specify code without changing any source code

Answer (score 0):

try eclipse plug-in spy tools to find existing function codes and description.

As the jdt, there are many api for users to do such things like find a JavaElement by string name.

However, it's a pity that few people are familiar to this part and all depends on you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The same functionality (Open Type under Cursor, Open File under Cursor) gives plugin called AnyEdit Tools (update site: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/). Look into its sources or just use it.

P.S. Useful hotkeys for plugin development/hacking:

- Shift+Alt+F1 - Plugin Selection Spy, shows detailed information about current window/editor/selection (contributing plugin, classes, selection etc.)
- Shift+Alt+F3 - Show Contributing Plug-in, shows which plugin has contributed active window